# PDF font renderings in Yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite

It seems that, on my computer, Yosemite Preview (and also Skim) display pdf fonts very differently than Maverick Preview (and also Yosemite Safari). There was no such problem in Maveric and the checkbox "Use LCD font smoothing when available" is checked. Moreover, the issue happens both with an Imac and an external display. Left is Safari, Right is Preview.

I have looked on the Internet but I could not find anyone with the same issue. Would someone know where does the problem come from?  If anyone thinks of a solution less drastic than a clean installation, I'd be glad to hear it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Preview (and Skim) no longer uses subpixel rendering, while Safari and Quick Look do when LCD font smoothing option is on (https://twitter.com/makotokanazawa/status/524481913558298624). As a result, PDF in Preview looks jaggy on a non-retina display. The difference is not as stark on my retina MBP.

Answer (score 0):

It also appears that preview and skim look very differently:

[image]

Preview.app is on the left, Skim.app is on the right.  Unfortunately, Preview is incapable of monitoring files for changes.